# Filter dataframe when all columns are NA in `dplyr`

Tags: r, dplyr

This is surely a simple question (if one knows the answer) but I still couldn't find guidance on SO: I have a dataframe with lots of rows that only have `NA` across all columns (after a `lead` operation). I want to remove those rows:

```
df <- structure(list(line = c("0001", NA, "0002", NA, "0003", NA, "0004", 
                              NA, "0005", NA), 
                     speaker = c(NA, NA, "ID16.C-U", NA, NA, NA, "ID16.B-U", NA, NA, NA), 
                     utterance = c("7.060", NA, "  ah-ha,", NA, "0.304", NA, "  °°yes°°", NA, "7.740", NA), 
                     timestamp = c(NA, "00:00:00.000 - 00:00:07.060", NA, "00:00:07.060 - 00:00:07.660", NA, 
                                   "00:00:07.660 - 00:00:07.964", NA, "00:00:07.964 - 00:00:08.610", NA, 
                                   "00:00:08.610 - 00:00:16.350")), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")
```

But neither this:

```
df %>%
  mutate(timestamp = lead(timestamp)) %>%
  filter(across(everything(), ~!is.na(.)))
```

nor this works:

```
df %>%
  mutate(timestamp = lead(timestamp)) %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  filter(c_across(everything(), ~!is.na(.)))
```

What's the solution?

**Expected**:

```
  line  speaker utterance                   timestamp
1 0001     <NA>     7.060 00:00:00.000 - 00:00:07.060
3 0002 ID16.C-U    ah-ha, 00:00:07.060 - 00:00:07.660
5 0003     <NA>     0.304 00:00:07.660 - 00:00:07.964
7 0004 ID16.B-U   °°yes°° 00:00:07.964 - 00:00:08.610
9 0005     <NA>     7.740 00:00:08.610 - 00:00:16.350
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dplyr` has new functions [`if_all()` and `if_any()`](https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2021/02/dplyr-1-0-4-if-any/) to handle cases like these:

```
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)

df %>% 
    mutate(timestamp = lead(timestamp)) %>%
    filter(!if_all(everything(), is.na))
#>   line  speaker utterance                   timestamp
#> 1 0001     <NA>     7.060 00:00:00.000 - 00:00:07.060
#> 2 0002 ID16.C-U    ah-ha, 00:00:07.060 - 00:00:07.660
#> 3 0003     <NA>     0.304 00:00:07.660 - 00:00:07.964
#> 4 0004 ID16.B-U   °°yes°° 00:00:07.964 - 00:00:08.610
#> 5 0005     <NA>     7.740 00:00:08.610 - 00:00:16.350
```

Comment: You forgot to apply OP's `mutate` to `lag` the `timestamp`... :=|.  But your solution works.

Answer (score 1):

Will this work?

```
df <- df %>% mutate(timestamp = lead(timestamp))
df[rowSums(is.na(df))!=ncol(df),]
```

pseudo-tidyverse version:

```
df %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(timestamp = dplyr::lead(timestamp)) %>% 
  dplyr::filter(rowSums(is.na(.))!=ncol(.))
```

Comment: Just put in the `mutate`command `mutate(timestamp = lead(timestamp)) %>%`

Comment: @chris, I added the lead-operation. I don't understand why you didn't just supply us with the data after the lead-operation in the first place?

Comment: So it's my fault you didn't supply the mutate?

Comment: you obviously know how to make a minimally reproducible example, so why not just do it?